# How to retrieve bus line including stop names?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I don't know much about OSM, OverpassTurbo, but would like to be able to query OSM about a given bus line, and retrieve the line and all the station names.

Then, I'll export the data as GPX so I can use them on my smartphone with no Internet access.

The following works, but I don't know how to customize it so it also retrieves the station names:

```
(
  relation["network"="NameOfBusLine"]["ref"="123"]({{bbox}});
);
```

Comment: This in my opinion is a too specific question, the question should be worded more generally, the use of the community would be greater.

Comment: This looks very similar to [this post](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/48721/overpass-query-to-retrieve-train-line-with-station-names)  and [that one](http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=54031) - please follow up there.